# trouble understanding Params object type in nextJS13

Tags: typescript, object, types, next.js13, dynamic-pages

I'm having difficulty understanding the Params type structure of nextJS.

the below code runs fine:

```
type Params={
    params:{userid:string}
}


export default async function UserPage({params:{userid}}:Params) {

    const userData:Promise<User>= getUser(userid);
    const userPostsData:Promise<Post[]>= getUserPosts(userid);

    // const [user,userPosts]=await Promise.all([userData,userPostsData]);

    const user=await userData;

  return (
    <>
        <h2>{user.name}</h2>
        <br />
        <Suspense fallback={`<h2>Loading</h2>`}>
            <UserPosts promise={userPostsData} />
        </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}
```

however I don't understand the use and why Params is structured like that.

when I change Params to this:

```
type Params={
    userid:string
}
```

and I change the parameter description to this:

```
export default async function UserPage({userid}:Params)
```

it gives an error.

So I know I did something wrong but I don't know what.

(btw i'm following this tutotrial: https://youtu.be/843nec-IvW0?feature=shared )

Answer (score 0):

`params` and `searchParams` are optional props in page component.
You can check the doc.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#props